# keep GET parameters through login process in Symfony app

Tags: php, eclipse, symfony, xdebug

I've got a Symfony 3 app that I'm developing in Eclipse (Neon).
When I Launch the Eclipse debugger, it spawns a browser aimed at the login page of my app, with the following parameters in the query string:

```
http://localhost/myapp/web/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ECLIPSE_DBGP&KEY=14793596093384
```

These parameters 'tie' the browsing session to XDebug, so I can set and hit breakpoints in my PHP code in Eclipse.

The problem is, the symfony app is somehow swallowing the GET parameters during the log in process.  If I set a breakpoint in `app.php` I can see the `$request` has the POST parameters:

```
_username:
_password:
_target_path:
_csrf_token:
```

but I can't find the GET parameters; `$request->query` is an empty array.

If I *manually* copy and paste the GET parameters into the URL after log in, the breakpoints work fine.

Is there a way for me to propagate the GET parameters through the login process of the Symfony app?

Comment: XDEBUG_SESSION_START parameter should be passed only once. XDebug starts the session and sends cookie to the client: https://xdebug.org/docs/remote#browser_session, so next requests from browser are not require this parameter.

Comment: in my experience, XDebug only works if the parameters are present in the page URL

Comment: https://xdebug.org/docs/remote#browser_session

Comment: any thoughts on why it wouldn't be working that way for me?

Comment: it depends on xdebug options in the php.ini, or IDE [settings](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Debugging_using_XDebug)

Comment: You may: 1) `xdebug.remote_autostart=1` in your php.ini (or xdebug.ini -- whatever you have got there) -- it will tell xdebug to attempt to debug every single request. Could be inconvenient .. but sometimes the only option (e.g. if it needs to be passed further via additional request which you wish to debug as well) 2) Install and use xdebug browser extension -- it will set xdebug cookie which is better than GET/POST parameter -- works with "normal" login pages/redirects/form submissions (but not sub-requests initiated inside PHP code, unless COOKIES manually get copied over as well).